# Is $\{x : x\sin{\frac{1}{x}} = 0 \}$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, trigonometry, metric-spaces

My professor says that $0$ is the only limit point of this set, and $0$ is in this set since $\sin$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, and it oscillates between these values so you can multiply $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ by $0$ and get a value of $0$, so this set contains all its limit points, which is just $0$ and thus it is a closed set. I am not convinced, is this true?

Comment: I don't understand how $0$ may be in this set since $x\sin{\frac 1x}$ is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: Doesn't $ \frac{1}{k\pi}$ map to $0$ for all integer $k$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that's informally written $f(x) = x \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ is undefined at $x=0$.

It does, however, admit a unique continuous extension to all of $\mathbb R$, and the zero set of this extension is a closed set.

The set you've written in the question, however, is not closed.

This is a good case for writing functions clearly. A function (like Gaul) is divided in 3 parts: the domain, the codomain, and the rule, i.e., it's a triple $(D, C, R)$, where $R$ is a subset of $D \times C$ satisfying certain properties. We usually describe such a function by writing

\begin{align}
f: D \to C : x \mapsto \text{some expression involving $x$},
\end{align}
which is a shorthand for 
\begin{align}
f = (D, C, \{ (x, \text{expression}) \mid x \in D \}).
\end{align}

When we get sloppy and just write down the expression, it's not clear what the intended domain is, but as a general rule, if the expression is undefined (e.g. $\frac{1}{x-1}$ is undefined at $x = 1$) or any factor or summand or function argument in the expression is undefined at at some point $a$, then $a$ is considered to not be in the domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you exclude $0$ from the domain of $xsin(\frac{1}{x})$ , then $xsin(\frac{1}{x})$ is a continuous function and the set is the inverse image of the closed set {$0$}.

Comment: Maybe it's also good to mention that if you exclude $0$ from the domain, you are considering closedness in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: What is an "inverse image?"

Comment: @EYES: the inverse image under a function f, of a set S is the set of points in the domain whose image is in S.

Comment: @ploosu2 : You're right, but like someone posted here, the function can b extended to be continuous in the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If the inverse image is $\{0\}$, doesn't that mean the domain is $\{0\}$?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: No, the inverse image _of_ {0} is the set of points that map to $0$ under $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The set 
$$
\left\{x : \lim_{t \to x} \left[ t \text{ sin}\frac{1}{t}  \right] =0\right\}
$$

is certainly closed, by the reasoning presented by your professor.

When you talk about 
$$
\left\{x :  x\text{ sin}\frac{1}{x}  = 0\right\}
$$
then you have to somehow define what 
$0 \text{ sin}\frac{1}{0}$ is.  While it is certainly reasonable to treat it as zero (since the sine function is bounded on the real line) it is also not required to definie it that way.  And if you define it as something other than zero, then the set is not closed.